# Significant slowdown on the Raspberry Pi while building cv_bridge

Tags: ros, memory

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I invoke the command below to rebuild the Catkin workspace:

```
sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/indigo -j2
```

It works perfectly fine for the first 115 packages or so but slows down to a major extent when it reaches the last few packages. It is obvious that the memory is running out, as I have a whole instance of `htop` running in another terminal.

I am using the `-j2` option to combat this problem. Yet the Raspberry Pi runs out of memory. `-j1` option is too slow and takes about two days. One of the solutions in my mind is to simulate a Raspberry Pi on my Arch. I would love to hear some suggestions from you guys.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251341/significant-slowdown-on-the-raspberry-pi-while-building-cv_bridge/) by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2017-01-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're using a Pi2 or Pi3 you can install Ubuntu and then install ROS through apt: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM ; then you don't have to build from source at all.

If you're doing lots of installations, you can do the build on one Pi, and then create a disk image and copy that instead of repeating the installation.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-01-06**:
Can you please ellaborate on one Pi? Using a distro such as Ubuntu would be too taxing on a Raspberry Pi for the applications that I am looking at.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-06**:
Why do you think Ubuntu will be "too taxing"? I've been running Ubuntu for quite a while and I haven't observed a significant overhead.

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-01-09**:
It's still a full GUI desktop environment running on the RPi. I selected Raspbian Lite, as experiments show that, it barely uses 78-80 MB of the RAM on the RPi. Also, what exactly did you mean by **one** Pi

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-09**:
By "one Pi" I mean a single Raspberry Pi (or Pi2 or Pi3).

**Comment by [sharan100](https://answers.ros.org/users/28742/sharan100/) on 2017-01-13**:
So I have gone by installing Ubuntu MATE on my Raspberry Pi and it seems to be a lot less hassle. I am still doubtful about [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/250822/how-to-install-lsd_slam-on-my-ros/) question though.